# Filter by column in Numbers

Tags: numbers

I have blanks in each row.  Can I hide them?

I want to be able to select a row and gather it together by getting rid of the empty cells.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear to me.  Do you just want to _hide_ the empty cells or find and _delete_ them altogether?  What is the reason you have blanks?  Is it due to imported data such as from a CSV file?  If the data is not sensitive, could you modify your question with a screenshot?  More information would be very helpful in assisting you with a solution. Cheers

Comment: It is a spreadsheet of passwords.  First column is website addresses.  Different sites require different details, therefore some cells ACROSS are empty.  I want to select a row and amalgamate the information so that there are no blanks across the row.  This is possible with "Filter Table' option, vertically.

Comment: Please add your above comments to the question for the benefit of clarity and perhaps to aid others with similar issues to find your question too.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the simplest way to accomplish this is to use the `CONCATENATE`
Function in a new column and then hide the others.

- At an appropriate place in your table, add a new column.  (Perhaps at the end)
- Add a formula such as `= TRIM ( CONCATENATE( A2, " ", A3 ))` adding in the calculation as many cells as needed.
- Drag the formula down the column.
- Now, hide the columns.

The Trim function removes the blank space you add in the formula in the event the first row is blank.

See examples below.

[image: Filtered table]

[image: Formula]

[image: Hide selected columns]

[image: Filtered table finished]

Comment: Hello, this is exactly the effect I am looking for, but without the formula.  I want to obtain the row information without the blanks as quickly as possible.  It is a spreadsheet of passwords that has to work quick.  I think this won't be possible unless there was an option to gather populated rows horizontally within the Numbers program.  Thanks for the long answer; the result is what I am looking for.

Comment: Well, even with Excel this has to be done with formulas due to the very nature of spreadsheet data display and design.  There are more robust ways of accomplishing this if you are willing to explore.  Once the formulas are in place, the data is formatted very quickly.  Hope you find a suitable solution. Cheers

Comment: Yeah, I think it's formula that will need to be used as even vertically Numbers displays the data in the column via drop down from the menu that pops out when you click the arrow at the top of the column.  Thanks anyway.